# Downtime-tolerant Linux scheduler with to-the-minute accuracy

Tags: cron

I have a server that I want to be able to schedule jobs on, and I need to be able to specify when those jobs happen to the minute. There will be a lot of jobs. (Things like sending e-mail notifications to clients).

This sounds like the perfect job for cron, however, I need to be able to handle downtime. In the event of downtime, I can't wait till anacron runs at the end of the day to reconcile all the missed tasks.

If I have a bit of downtime, I need all the overdue tasks to be run at boot.

For example:

- Task is scheduled for 17:36
- Machine is shut down at 17:33
- Machine is booted at 17:40
- Task is now overdue, and should be run as soon as possible.

Is there a way to change anacron into something that runs at boot and runs all the overdue cron jobs?

Or, is there some other common solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cron/anacron are not built with fault-tolerant or highly available scenarios. If your jobs are very critical I think Jobscheduler http://www.sos-berlin.com/jobscheduler-features will be beneficial for you. Just a headsup , its not easy to setup and will take a little time to get acquainted, but it is the best tool for scheduling

Answer (score 2):

Any of the work queue systems out there should be able to do it.  Celery, Resque, Sidekiq, backgroundjob, etc etc etc.  Some of them have it built-in, others have a plugin that adds chronological dispatch.